# request mothod not working for https://arxiv.org pdf files

Tags: node.js, pdf, request

I am using request method for get the file stream, its works for all pdf files but when i try to get https://arxiv.org website pdfs (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf) then its not working.

For https://arxiv.org/ website pdfs its giving 403 fobidden status code whereas for other websites pdf files it return 200 status code.

Here is my code for getting other website pdfs

```
   request('http://uberthings.com/mobile/intro_to_mobile.pdf', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

// Return 200 status code

Here is my code for https://arxiv.org other website pdfs

```
  request('https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

// Return 403 status code

Any Idea why request method for particular website (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf) is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Access Denied 403.*
Sadly, your client does not supply a proper User-Agent and is consequently excluded.

to fix this pass User-Agent in request headers

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf',
    headers: {
        'Referer': 'https://arxiv.org',
        'User-Agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)'
    }
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

List of user agents for User Agent https://gist.github.com/enginnr/ed572cf5c324ad04ff2e