# Axios request to arxiv randomly fails

Tags: javascript, express, axios, google-cloud-functions, arxiv

I am building a simple web app that basically gets a single .pdf file from arxiv, then parses the text from that file. The backend is a cloud function hosted by the firebase environment, and the request for the .pdf file is really straight forward:

```
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://paperfire-ada3a.web.app')
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    const isArxivUrl = (url) => {
        return url.includes('arxiv.org') || url.includes('arxiv');
      };
    const uid = req.headers['user-id'];
    const pdfUrl = req.body; // Expecting a link in the body
    if (!isArxivUrl(pdfUrl)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'The URL must be from arXiv.' });
      }
    
    if (!pdfUrl) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No URL provided.' });
    }

    try {


        let pdfResponse;
        try {
          pdfResponse = await axios.get(pdfUrl, {
              responseType: 'arraybuffer',
              headers: {
                  'Referer': 'https://arxiv.org',
                  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36' // Set a realistic User-agent header
                },
              retry: {
                attempts: 3,
                minTimeout: 1000, // Minimum delay between retries in milliseconds
                maxTimeout: 5000, // Maximum delay between retries in milliseconds
                factor: 2 // Exponential backoff: Double the delay for each retry
              }
          });
      } catch (axiosError) {
          console.error("Axios Error: ", axiosError);
          return res.status(512).json({ error: "Error fetching PDF from URL.", details: axiosError.message });
      }
const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(pdfResponse.data, 'binary');
```

The issue is that the succes rate of the request is not consistent at all, meaning that a lot of the times the request is successful, and other times the request results in a `403 ERR_BAD_REQUEST`. I tried with several User-Agents as other stack overflow posts suggest, but nothing seems to be working, the arxiv server just randomly stops my requests and I don't understand why. This happens from both postman and front-end. The URL that I provide as input is of type: `https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.02851.pdf`. Even if I try with the URL provided by arxiv for developers: `https://export.arxiv.org/pdf/2306.02851.pdf`, the success rate is not consistent.

**Update 1:**
It seems that changing the User-Agent value impacts the request. Changing it to something simple such as `User-Agent: 'PaperFire'` made every request to be successful, but only for a number of times/request. Meaning that after I downloaded only one specific paper several times, I started to receive `403 ERR_BAD_REQUEST` for that .pdf, while other requests are successful.

**Update 2:**
Everything seems to be working perfectly from the localhost, using the cloudfunction from the firebase emulators.

Comment: It sounds like you have feedback for the people who host that arxiv service, which is not something the volunteers on Stack Overflow can really help you with. If you are issuing the exact same request multiple times with different results, then I'm not sure how this could be a problem on your end that we can easily resolve.

Comment: I found out similar questions such as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073401/request-mothod-not-working-for-https-arxiv-org-pdf-files), that's why I thought that the question is fit for Stack Overflow @DougStevenson

Comment: The difference is that the other question is showing a specific error message as a result of a failure that happens consistently.  If you're saying something fails randomly with no variation on your side, and the error is not coming from your side, what can we do? Ideally we need example code that fails reliably, shown in a way that anyone can copy and run the code to observe the same result without variance.

Comment: @FlaviusBiras, which axios version using it?

Comment: @BenchVue `^1.6.2`

Comment: That web site "https://paperfire-ada3a.web.app/" google OpenID Connect (OIDC) login based upload service with cryptographic key (AIzaSyDT7NDe1bf4k_vR_Jr-smGbMarb2tRvh0Q) . So you cannot program in your local `express` program because call back URL configured "paperfire-ada3a.web.app" not your local.

Comment: The website [link](paperfire-ada3a.web.app) represents the front end of my app, and I am hosting it in firebase, so it is not local. I am not sure what you mean @BenchVue

Comment: Oh, it is "paperfire-ada3a.web.app" your app? I thought you are hacking that web site in your local. Your service to convert mp3 from uploaded pdf file. Are you backend develop for ""paperfire-ada3a.web.app" or just your own firebase service?

Comment: I am developing both the front-end and the backend of this app. The front sends an arxiv link to the backend, which is an express app hosted as a cloud function. I posted the code for this function in the question. The backend takes the link and does an axios get to download the .pdf to obtain an .mp3 file, and the axios fails RANDOMLY with a 403 error code.

Comment: The OIDC token service 1 hour(3600 seconds) valid access token POST API call. If expired to get new access token by refresh token. Did you check token expired to "paperfire-ada3a.firebaseapp.com" for google API call?

Comment: @BenchVue I tought that as long as I stay logged in, the token does not expire. Do you think this could be the cause for the 403 error at the axios call?

Comment: I guess you missed scope in access token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810233/cant-access-firebase-database-via-http-rest-error-403-forbidden)

Comment: @BenchVue In the question that you mention, firebase throws a 403 Error. In my case, arxiv gives me a 403 Error when I try to download a .pdf from their site